# Reprojecting GeoTIFFs to WGS84/UTM

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, utm

I'm using `libgeotiff` and `proj4` to read and process GeoTIFFs. After reading the file, I want to get the corner coordinates in WGS84/UTM but there are so many functions and parameters to try and understand,

My current function goes like this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOOL CGeoTIFFImporter::GetUTMCorner(Corners cnr, double& x, double& y)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    BOOL bRet = FALSE;
    if (m_bIsGeoTIFF)
    {
        x = -DBL_MAX;
        y = -DBL_MAX;
        double xtmp = -DBL_MAX;
        double ytmp = -DBL_MAX;
        CString spjUTM = "";
        projPJ pjUTM, pjPJ;
        char *pszProjection;

        switch (cnr)
        {
            case LowerLeft: x = 0.0; y = m_Ypx; break;
            case LowerRight: x = m_Xpx; y = m_Ypx; break;
            case UpperLeft: x = 0.0; y = 0.0; break;
            case UpperRight: x = m_Xpx; y = 0.0; break;
        }

        // Try to transform the coordinate into PCS space
        bRet = GTIFImageToPCS(m_pGTF, &x, &y);

        if (bRet && m_GTFDef.Zone != 0)
        {
            xtmp = x; ytmp = y;
            if (m_GTFDef.Model == ModelTypeGeographic)
            {
            }
            else if (!GTIFProj4ToLatLong(&m_GTFDef, 1, &xtmp, &ytmp))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            spjUTM.Format("+proj=utm +zone=%d +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84", UTMZone(xtmp));

            pjUTM = pj_init_plus(spjUTM);

            if (pjUTM == NULL)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            pszProjection = GTIFGetProj4Defn(&m_GTFDef);

            if (pszProjection == NULL)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
            pjPJ = pj_init_plus(pszProjection);
            free(pszProjection);

            if (pjPJ == NULL)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            bRet = (pj_transform(pjPJ, pjUTM, 1, 1, &x, &y, NULL) == 0);
        }
    }
    return bRet;
}
```

Somewhat unsurprisingly given my state of knowledge on the subject, this doesn't work. Can anyone give me some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Typical! I've been Googling this for a week without success - as soon as I post this, I find the answer - I think! Just testing `(ytmp > 0)` and adding `+north` or `+south` as appropriate. Still, I'll leave this open for comments for a while, because I'm not 100% sure!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Hopefully not a transformation, as this can easily be done in GDAL: http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html (as I'm sure you're aware!)

Comment: I'm importing and placing GeoTIFFs in my CAD app, but I want to stick to UTM and WGS84 for simplicity and planar-ness. GDAL is great, but it has a massive overhead for this one function I actually want.

Comment: So you are writing an app and are writing GeoTIFF reading functionality? Fair enough. But many applications use GDAL for this and it means that you can load more than just GeoTIFFs: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/SoftwareUsingGdal

Comment: That's true, but several tens of MBs of DLLs to support functions I'm don't (currently) want or need is just too bloaty for me! If I can add GeoTIFF and KML support, that'll do me for now.